# Searching multiple SQL tables for certain row then return row as well as table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am somewhat new to SQL so I am still trying to learn some of the simple things.

Right now I have multiple tables for different levels of access on my application (Customers, Representatives, Managers).

A username CANNOT be shared between these tables. What I am getting held up at is trying to select the users row based on the username.

I would easily know how to do this if there were just one table for users but I am not really sure how to search multiple tables at the same time.

Also if a username is found, is there a way to return the name of the table that it found that username in?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

A simple UNION might be all you need

```
SELECT 'table1' as tab, c1, c2, c3 FROM table1 WHERE uid='xxx'
UNION
SELECT 'table2' as tab, c1, c2, c3 FROM table2 WHERE uid='xxx'
UNION
SELECT 'table3' as tab, c1, c2, c3 FROM table3 WHERE uid='xxx'
```

As you will only get one row returned as user `xxx` can only exist in one of the tables you get all the columns you are interested in plus the first column containing your table name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all tables' layouts are the same:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  'customers' tn, *
        FROM    customers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'managers' tn, *
        FROM    managers
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'representatives' tn, *
        FROM    representatives
        ) q
WHERE   username = @myusername
```